# How to remove item array with hasOwnProperty()

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

after setup a simple RNApp,
And select some photos from cameraRoll with hasOwnProperty i'd like to remove the selected image, and i did the same with select!
but image selected did not remove using hasOwnProperty!
Please, someone can clarify who to remove, add from arrays, with hasOwnProperty?

**Select**

```
selectPhoto(ind) {
    let obj = this.state.selected_photos;

    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(ind)) {
      delete obj[ind];
    } else {
      obj[ind] = true;
    }
    this.setState({
      selected_photos: obj
    });
  }

  goPostForm() {
    let photos_uri = [];
    Object.keys(this.state.selected_photos).map((d, k) => {
      photos_uri.push(this.state.photos[k].node.image.uri);
    });
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Post", {
      image: "",
      photos: photos_uri
    });
  }
```

**Remove**

> state = {
>       delete_image: false,
>       delete_photos: new Object(),   };

```
 deletePhoto(ind) {
    let obj = this.state.delete_photos;
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(ind)) {
      delete obj[ind];
    } else {
      obj[ind] = true;
    }
    this.setState({
      delete_photos: obj
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    let image = params ? params.image : null;
    let photos = params
      ? params.hasOwnProperty("photos")
        ? params.photos
        : []
      : [];
    return (
      <View
        style={{ paddingTop: 100, paddingHorizontal: 30, flexDirection: "row" }}
      >
        {!image && photos.length > 0
          ? photos.map((d, k) => {
              if (!this.state.delete_photos.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                return (
                  <View key={k}>
                    <Image
                      source={{ uri: d }}
                      style={{ resizeMode: "contain", height: 72, width: 72 }}
                    />
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.deletePhoto(k)}>
                      <Text>Delete image</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
                );
              }
            })
          : null}
```

Comment: `hasOwnProperty`, as its name suggests, just returns true if the property exists on the object. How would one use that to "remove, add from arrays"?

Comment: @HereticMonkey with   if (obj.hasOwnProperty(ind)) {
      delete obj[ind];
    } else {

Comment: Okay, so it's `delete` that does the removing, not `hasOwnProperty`. I'm not sure why you're so keen on using `hasOwnProperty` on an array when you can check for the existence of an array index using `if (array[index])` or `if (index in array)` but to each their own. But it seems like you already know how to delete something from an array, and you're already using `push` and direct array access (`obj[ind] = true`) to add items to arrays, so what's the question?

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes, because i'm trying to get the images from cameraRoll and post it with rn-fetch-blob. 
The issue is that is not removing still posting with the images

Answer (score 0):

Use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to delete from an array.

```js
const arr = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']

const indexToDelete = arr.findIndex(item => item === 'banana')

if (indexToDelete > -1) {
  arr.splice(indexToDelete, 1)
}

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: zaytrix thank you for your amswer but i still not understood how to apply on that sistuation